# CORS method parameter does not seem to work?

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api

I have enabled CORS in an ASP.NET Web API project. Currently, it is set to only allow access via my client application and looks like this:

```
[EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:44051", "*","post")]
public class ProductsController : ApiController
```

However, this is allowing GET requests as well. I thought that by specifying "post" as the last parameter that only POST requests would be permitted cross-origin.

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Just a guess but maybe the CORS policy isn't applying to you since you are not from a different origin?

Comment: If I take off the attribute, I get the "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present" error. So I assume that CORS policy is applied.

Comment: Are you testing with a browser, extension like postman or a tool like Fiddler?  Maybe test with a variety of clients and see if you see anything different.  is your client also on localhost:44051 ?

Comment: I'm testing with Chrome. It is my client that is on 44051. My Web API service is on a different port.

Answer (score 0):

for enable all domains

1. [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

Set the Allowed HTTP Methods

The methods parameter of the [EnableCors] attribute specifies which HTTP methods are allowed to access the resource. To allow all methods, use the wildcard value “*”. The following example allows only GET and POST requests.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://www.example.com", headers: "*", methods: "get,post")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get() { ... }
    public HttpResponseMessage Post() { ... }
    public HttpResponseMessage Put() { ... }    
}
```

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: This is directly from the documentation. I don't see how this answers my question. I am using the attribute as documented and specifying "post". Since this attribute "specifies which HTTP method are allowed" ... then my client application should not be able to access the GET in my example. But it can. Does my example work for you?